# I want to show Tick Image after any value selected in dropdownlist without page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my source code. I taken a one dropdownlist and trying to show tick image after dropdown selection but I want to avoid page refresh, I tried update panel also but its not working:

```
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbExpectedMarks1"  CssClass="form-control chzn-select" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbExpectedMarks1_SelectedIndexChanged1" >
      <asp:ListItem>Average</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> First Class</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Merit</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Distinction</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
   <asp:ImageButton ID="Img123" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/glipcon_ok.png" Visible="false" style="Height:22px;Width:22px;"  ImageAlign="Middle" />
</div>
```

My .cs code is

```
 protected void cmbExpectedMarks1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Img123.Visible = true;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with the following JS snippet.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    let image123 = document.getElementById('Img123');
    document.getElementById('cmbExpectedMarks1').onchange =
       function changeEventHandler(event) {
           if(!event.target.value) {
               image123.style.display = "none";
           } else {
               image123.style.display = "block";
           }
       }
}, false);
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working on my code ,can u help me out please

Comment: add this code inside <script> </script> tags and put the script tag just before the end of the </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `UpdatePanel` (and avoid any JavaScript/jQuery code) the following should work:

WebForm:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:DropDownList
                ID="cmbExpectedMarks1"
                CssClass="form-control chzn-select"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                runat="server"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbExpectedMarks1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Average</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> First Class</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Merit</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Distinction</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="Img123" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/glipcon_ok.png" Visible="false" Style="height: 22px; width: 22px;" ImageAlign="Middle" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void cmbExpectedMarks1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Img123.Visible = true;
}
```